# Solution of differential equation $y''+y=x+1,y(0)=1$ disagree with wolfram result

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve $$y''+y=x+1,y(0)=1$$
**My solution:**

I solve he differential equation and I get $$y=c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x+x+1$$ Then I know that $y(0)=1\implies c_1=0$

Finally I get $$\boxed{y=c\sin x+x+1}$$

**Wolfram solution:**

if I type in wolfram solver $y''+y=x+1,y(0)=1$ and the result I get is $$\boxed{y=c\sin x}$$

Which one is the correct solution finally?

Comment: $y(0) = c \sin(0) = 0 \neq 1$

Comment: At least we can tell that the last solution doesn't satisfy the initial condiition.

Comment: you need a second boundary condition...

Comment: My guess is that you've stumbled upon a bug in Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: @tired That's why there is a free parameter, $c$ in the solution. DimitriC:  Looks like you've found another WolframAlpha bug! Clearly their solution is incorrect

Comment: Mathematica fixes this. Could you link to wolfram alphas solution?

Comment: You have to type though '' y''+y=x+1,y(0)=1 "
http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=e602dcdecb1843943960b5197efd3f2a

Comment: WolframAlpha misbehaving: http://tinyurl.com/pcs87yo

Comment: I see. I suggest to move this to Mathematica.SE.

Comment: Moral of the story: trust your own mathematics and logic. Your solution is correct.

Comment: @mickep how can I move it to Mathematica SE?

Comment: Odd. Just tried it in Wolfram Alpha. It correctly gives the "sample individual solution" as y=x+1, and correctly plots a general solution with c non-zero. But it states the solution without the x+1. So it is a fairly minor bug. If you do more than glance at the output, it is obvious that you need to add in the x+1.

Comment: There is no need to move the question to Mathematica SE, if your question is what is the correct solution to your ODE. If you want to know *why* WolframAlpha might be giving this incorrect answer, then ask that question there.

Comment: Completing the query to "y''+y=x+1,y(0)=1, y'(0)=a" gives again the correct solution.

Comment: @mickep Questions about Wolfram Alpha are [off topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on [Mathematica.se], except if it's about using WA within Mathematica.

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry, then my suggestion is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Answer:

$y''+y=-c\sin x+c\sin x+x+1=x+1$

Also $y(0)=1$. The same cannot be said about WA's answer.